# How to do internationalization (i18n) on javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?

Tags: javafx, datepicker, internationalization, javafx-8

I am developing a desktop application using JavaFX. 
**javafx.scene.control.DatePicker** is a good control with many options for me until I need to change some of its texts to my language.

But I dont know how to do, I did some Google searching but no result.
 Please refer to below image for intuition. The texts which I need to change are red-underlined. Could any guru show me a solution ?

[image: The text I want to change is red-underlined]
Thank you guys in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
```

> Sets the default locale for this instance of the Java Virtual Machine. This does not affect the host locale.

Comment: Thank you, I used Locale.setDefault(new Locale("vi", "vn")); and was satisfied. The texts are constants of locale setting but I don't think I need further customization on them :)